# flask + angular bootstrap ui + datepicker = wrong date

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i'm just trying to use datepicker about ui-bootstrap but when data is sent i got always a day before and hour is set at 23:00.

You can find all my try on jsbin link below.

**output:**
`"[u'2015-02-25T23:00:00.000Z', {}, []]"`

**link to the code**:
http://jsbin.com/canulixaho/2/edit

i need to pass only Year - Month - Day but i can manage it in python after.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a typical time zone issue. if your browser/os is running on timezone Zurich (Utc+1) and you post a js date like 20. Jan 00:00 it is normally rendered in Utc in json: 19. Jan 23:00. The Z at the end of your output means: this is in Utc.

If you send the same Utc date back to the same browser it will automatically display it as 20. Jan 00:00 again.

So, if my assumption of a timezone <> Utc is true it all works correctly and as designed.

If you want to see the same representation on the server as you see in the client you either need to run your server in the same timezone or use software like moment-timezone.js to format in the desired timezone.

If you don't want to deal with timezone issues, covert your date to a formatted string in the client and send the string to your backed.